'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart', this URI sometimes can't be recognized with the same code
What I want

I wanted to make '.dart_tool/flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart' and actually it's made. enter image description here
There are seperated .arb files and they should be merged through arb_merger package. This also works well.
I need to do localization with AppLocalizations class with 'import package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';'  this URI.

** Error **
But I got Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart'. in import statement and Undefined 'AppLocalizations error.
With the same code, the codes work sometimes, but do not work on ocaasion. It's so confusing.
What I did
This is my pubspec.yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.19.0
  
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^4.0.0

arb_merger:
  supported_locales: ["en", "zh", "ko"]
  input_filepath: "lib/l10n"

flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/icons/  
    - assets/images/splash/
    - assets/images/home/
  uses-material-design: true
  generate: true

This is my l10n.yaml
arb-dir: lib/l10n
template-arb-file: en.arb
nullable-getter: false
output-localization-file: app_localizations.dart
output-class: AppLocalizations
untranslated-messages-file: untranslated_messages.json

This is the portion of main.dart.
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';


MaterialApp.router(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  scrollBehavior: const MaterialScrollBehavior().copyWith(dragDevices: {
    PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
    PointerDeviceKind.touch,
    PointerDeviceKind.trackpad,
    PointerDeviceKind.stylus,
    PointerDeviceKind.unknown,
  }),
  themeMode: state.themeMode,
  theme: AppThemes.getThemeData(state.themeColor, false),
  darkTheme: AppThemes.getThemeData(state.themeColor, true),
  locale: state.locale,
  localizationsDelegates: AppLocalizations.localizationsDelegates,
  supportedLocales: AppLocalizations.supportedLocales,
  routerConfig: Routing.router,
);

with these codes, I already try to restart the IDE(VSCode), flutter clean, flutter gen-l10n and everything.
I need your help to solve this problem

try this flutter pub global run intl_utils:generate and whether it is generated or not

@Adan intl_en.dart file generated but I want the en.dart file to be recognized

I solved it. Just see https://github.com/dart-lang/build/issues/3705
